# JTidy reports "3 errors were found!"... but does not say what they are

Tags: java, jtidy

I have a large block of programmatically generated HTML. I ran it through Tidy (version r938) with the following Java code:

```
StringReader inStr = new StringReader(htmlInput);
StringWriter outStr = new StringWriter();
Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
tidy.setXHTML(true);
tidy.parseDOM(inStr, outStr);
```

I get the following output:

```
InputStream: Document content looks like HTML 4.01 Transitional
247 warnings, 3 errors were found!
This document has errors that must be fixed before
using HTML Tidy to generate a tidied up version.
```

Trouble is, Tidy doesn't tell me what 3 errors it found.

I'm fibbing here a little. The output above actually follows a long list of all 247 warnings (mostly trimming out empty `div` elements). I can suppress those with `tidy.setShowWarnings(false)`; either way, I see no error report, so I can't figure out what I need to fix. 300Kb of HTML is too much for me to eyeball.

I've tried numerous approaches to finding the error. I can't run it through validate.w3.org, sadly, as the HTML file is on a proprietary network. The most informative approach was to open it in IntelliJ IDEA; this revealed a dozen or so duplicate div IDs, which I fixed. Errors still occurred.

I've looked around for other mentions of this problem. While I find plenty of hits on things like ["How can I get the error/warning messages out of the parsed HTML using JTidy?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455980/how-can-i-get-the-error-warning-messages-out-of-the-parsed-html-using-jtidy), they all appear to be asking for dissimilar things, or assume conditions that simply aren't holding for me. I'm getting warnings just fine, for example; it's the *errors* I need, and they're not being reported, even if I call `setShowErrors(100)` or something.

Am I going to have to dive into Tidy's source code and debug it, starting where it reports errors? Or is there something much simpler I could do?

Comment: Can you provide a small html document that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Your timing is excellent; turns out I managed to produce one just this morning. It warrants a new SO question. ...I noticed your handle on JTidy's Sourceforge page, so I'm very hopeful about your chances of addressing it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40849872/jtidy-cant-handle-html-tags-inside-script-element

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I answered your other question now. By the way, I'm not one of the main developers of JTidy. It had already been abandoned for some time before I started using it, then I joined the project and did a lot of work fixing and updating things, made a couple of releases, but then I kinda abandoned it too due to lack of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing to track down the errors:

1. **Download JTidy's source.** Most people should be able to go straight to [the source](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jtidy/files/).
2. **Unzip the source into my dev area.** Right on top of my existing source code. This also meant removing the Maven entry for JTidy from my pom.xml. (It also meant beating IntelliJ into submission (re: editing the relevant .iml files and restarting IJ a lot) when it got extremely confused by this.)
3. **Set a breakpoint in Report.error.** The first line of `org.w3.tidy.Report.error()` increments `lexer.errors`; `error()` is called from many places in the lexer.
4. **Run my program in debug mode.** Expect this to take a little while if the input HTML is large; a 300k file took around 10-15 seconds on my machine to stop on an error that turned out to be at the very end of the file.
5. **Look at the contents of lexbuf.** `lexbuf` is a byte array, so your IDE might not show it as text. It might also be large. You probably want to look at what index the lexer was looking at within `lexbuf`. If you have to, take that section of the byte array and cross-reference it with an ASCII table to get the text.
6. **Search for that text in your HTML.** Assuming it appears only once, there's your error. (In my case, it appeared exactly three times, and sure enough, I had three errors reported.)

This was much more involved than it probably should have been. I suspect `Report.error()` was being called inappropriately.

In my case, `error()` was called with the constant `BAD_CDATA_CONTENT`. This constant is used only by `Report.warning()`. `error()` doesn't know what to do with it, and just *exits silently with no message at all*. If I change the call in `Lexer.getCDATA()` from `error()` to `warning()`, I get the exact line and column of my error. (I also get what appears to be reasonably well-formed XHTML, instead of an empty document.)

I'd submit a ticket to the JTidy project with some suggestions, but SourceForge isn't letting me log in for some reason. So, here:

- Given that this "error" appears not to doom the document to unparseability, I'll tentatively suggest that that call be made a warning instead. (In my specific case, it was an HTML tag inside a string constant or comment inside a `script` element; shouldn't have hurt anything. [I asked another question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40849872/jtidy-cant-handle-html-tags-inside-script-element), just in case.)
- `Report.error()` should have a default case that reports an unhandled error code if it gets one.

Hope this helps anyone else having what I'm guessing is a rather esoteric problem.